# Run a MATLAB script from Windows DOS prompt

Tags: matlab, command-line, batch-file, dos

I am trying to run a Matlab script from Windows command prompt but I can't execute it sometimes.  The script runs fine when manually launched.  Matlab version is 2011a and Windows is Server 2003 SP2.  Details:

Script `mytask.m` is located inside say `E:\Production\Project`.  This is `SAVED` on Matlab's path.

When I place mytask.m inside `bin` folder, it executes fine by the command:

```
     `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011a\bin>matlab -r mytask`
```

If you delete it and try to access it at its original location, the script doesn't run although Matlab editor window is launched:

```
     `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011a\bin>matlab -r "E:\Production\Project\mytask"
```

Any suggestions please?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [syntax](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/matlabwindows.html) for `matlab -r` is

```
matlab -r "statement"
```

In other words, you need to provide some executable commands as the statement. For example:

```
matlab -r "run E:\Production\Project\mytask"
```

However, it seems that matlab does not load the customized paths in this way. If you have some customized paths, you probably have to define them in `startup.m` and place this `startup.m` in the directory where you invoke matlab.

I didn't check myself, but if you define `E:\Production\Project\` as the path in `startup.m`, you probably can run `matlab -r mytask` without problem, as `mytask` will be recognized as a user function/script.

A simple example of `startup.m`

```
path(path, 'E:\Production\Project\');
```

Comment: or you can simply do: `matlab -r "addpath('E:\Production\Project'); mytask"`

Comment: There's also a `matlab -sd <startdir>` command line option to start Matlab in a particular directory; you could point it at E:\Production\Project and then the path and relative file names would resolve. (Deprecated, you could also use a wrapper script to cd before launching.) Or you could make a wrapper script for mytask that uses mfilename('-fullpath') and adds the paths itself, to make the command lines simpler.